# How can I set the svn:needs-lock Subversion property through AnkhSVN plug-in with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, ankhsvn

I am using the AnkhSVN plug-in with Visual Studio 2008. I am using a free repository hosted on the web. I am not using a Subversion client for this repo, but managing everything with AnkhSVN plug-in (including adding solution file and project files to the new repository).

I want to add the `svn:needs-lock` property to these files. I wonder if I can do this task using AnkhSVN, or if I need to get another Subversion client for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Visual Studio.. In Tools - Options - Source Control, you can change the plug-in value to AnkhSVN.  After you do that, "subversion environment" appears in the tree under source control.  Select that, then you can check "automatically lock files on change without user confirmation".  I think this will accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can add and edit Subversion properties through Ankhsvn, see [the AnkhSVN Add Property documentation](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_add_property.html). However the behavior of Visual Studio varies depending on the object (solution, project, or file) selected in the Solution Explorer pane when the right mouse click menu is triggered. What is available from the Subversion sub-menu as well as the Add Properties dialog will vary depending on the object selected.

The list of `svn:` properties suggested by the plug-in varies depending on the object selected. While the `svn:needs-lock` property is suggested for an individual file, the property is not available for other objects.

In addition the `Subversion` menu item does not seem to be available on a right mouse click with multiple files selected (as of AnkhSVN version 2.6).

Comment: Yes, thank you. But, I am unable to do this in bulk, doing it file by file is tedious.

Comment: @grungean: Sometimes, using a GUI isn't the right answer. Why not do this using the Subversion command line client?