# practices for Subversion branch and trunk decisions and deleting files from SVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn, svnignore

I have a Subversion repository accessed via AnkhSVN Subversion Plug-in with Visual Studio 2005 and 2013 in a Windows development environment that needs to be cleaned up. Reading stackoverflow [Best practices for Subversion and Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732813/best-practices-for-subversion-and-visual-studio-projects) there is a bit of clutter to remove from the trunk.

I also want to branch the trunk to a side stream that will have few to no updates for the current release so that I can concentrate on the next release in the trunk. [Understanding branch use with Visual Studio 2010, AnkhSVN, and SVN 1.7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240078/understanding-branch-use-with-visual-studio-2010-ankhsvn-and-svn-1-7-4) indicates that I need more than the AnkhSVN plug-in for actions other than updating the repository and/or working copy.

It appears that Tortoise SVN GUI client is needed as well as the AnkhSVN plug-in. Is this correct?

What I would like to have after a repository update and pruning exercise is a current version in the repository trunk which will not have unneeded files however if I have to pull an earlier version from say a year ago, those pruned files will be part of what is pulled.

How do I create an ignore list for AnkhSVN with files that are already in the repository so that it will ignore files in the working folder and not update them into the Subversion repository in the future? It appears that if a file is new and has not been put into the Subversion repository, I can choose to ignore that file from the Pending Updates window of Visual Studio however what about existing files.

What about files that are not displayed in Visual Studio IDE such as .dsw (left over solution file from Visual Studio 6.1) or .suo files which are in the repository and should be removed?

What are the repercussions of deleting currently unused files in the Subversion repository trunk? Does a delete delete all versions of the file in the trunk and branches or just the trunk? Does it do an actual delete or is the file just marked as deleted and unused for the future versions?

Is there a way to mark a file as being unused beginning with a particular update so that pulling from the repository using that update or later will not include files marked as unused? However if an earlier version is pulled, perhaps for researching a field report of an earlier version, the file which may need needed for that earlier version be available?

It looks like AnkhSVN has a merge capability to allow me to merge changes from trunk into a branch. It looks like I would pull down a clean copy of the branch and then do a merge into my working copy from the trunk. Then I would clean up any conflicts, test, and then update the branch with the merged working copy. Is that correct?

Comment: Experiments with Visual Studio 2013 using AnhkSVN plug-in, I think 2.6, I was able to access a Subversion test server running through Apache2 DAV to create a new project tree root with a trunk, upload sample source into the new project tree trunk, make a copy of the trunk into a branch, switch to the branch, modify the source, update the branch, switch back to the trunk, and merge the modifications in the branch back into the trunk. The source was a very simple console application. Next step is to setup a linux box with Subversion and test with the real code base in a test environment.

Comment: The Subversion web site at https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html  has a link to an online copy of the O'Reilly book on Subversion located at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ which seems to be updated from time to time. At this time the Subversion version covered is 1.7 according to the cover page. Using a web browser to access my Subversion repository root, I see that my copy of Subversion is at 1.6.6 (footer says "Powered by Subversion version 1.6.6 (r40053).").

Comment: [Can I set svn properties through ankhsvn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873732/can-i-set-svn-properties-through-ankhsvn). See this part of AnkhSVN documentation [AnkhSVN > Version control operations >
Add a Subversion property](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_add_property.html). This article [Source Control for Visual Studio 2008: VisualSVN Server, TortoiseSVN, & AnkhSVN - Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31153/Source-Control-for-Visual-Studio-VisualSVN-Se) has an older writeup about using Subversion with Visual Studio 2008.